# SAS proc report RTF table column widths not aligning with specified widths

Tags: sas, report, rtf, ods

When generating a SAS table in format .rtf using `proc report`, the column widths are not aligning to their specified widths. This is resulting in column headings taking up multiple lines, and a few values being truncated, which I want to avoid.

Using the data:

```
/* Insert data */
data aaa;
   input cohort $ color $ sum $ pctn $;
   datalines;
group_1 dark_yellow 2   12.500%
group_2 orange  6   37.500%
group_2 dark_green  8   50.000%
overall orange  6   30.000%
overall dark_green  8   42.250%
;
run;
```

And this code to generate a .rtf file with column widths of 7, 11, 16 and 30 respectively:

```
/* Output settings */
options nocenter nodate nonumber missing=' ' orientation=landscape linesize=116 pagesize=42;    * page settings;
ods output close;       * close ods output;
ods rtf close;          * close ods rtf;
ods listing close;      * close ods listing;
footnote "Table generated on %sysfunc(date(), worddatx.w.)";            * insert date below report;
ods rtf file = "C:\Astudies\Colors.rtf" bodytitle;

/* Generate table */
proc report data=aaa nowd split='~';
column cohort color sum pctn;
define cohort   /order order=data       width=7     left    'Cohort';
define color        /display            width=11    left    'Color';
define sum          /display            width=16    left    'Number of colors';
define pctn         /display            width=30    left    'Percentage of total colors (%)';
title 'Painting';
title2'Common colours per cohort';
run;

title;              * remove any titles;
footnote;           * remove any footnotes;
ods rtf close;      * close ods rtf;
ods listing;
```

This results in this table. Columns 3-4 have titles spanning multiple lines (their lengths are 16 and 30 characters respectively). Column 2 has truncated values where the max character length (dark_yellow) should be 11.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a `PROC REPORT` column style `width=` property in the `DEFINE` *column* `/ STYLE=[]` option.

**Sample Code**

This example presumes 10" of landscape real estate, with relative (unitless) column widths of 7, 11, 16, and 30.  A %SYSEVALF computation maps the relative widths to explicit inches to be used in the ODS RTF rendering.

```
proc report data=aaa nowd split='~'
;
column cohort color sum pctn;
define cohort   /order order=data       left    'Cohort'                          style=[width=%sysevalf(10 *  7 / (7+11+16+30))in];
define color        /display            left    'Color'                           style=[width=%sysevalf(10 * 11 / (7+11+16+30))in];
define sum          /display            left    'Number of colors'                style=[width=%sysevalf(10 * 16 / (7+11+16+30))in];;
define pctn         /display            left    'Percentage of total colors (%)'  style=[width=%sysevalf(10 * 30 / (7+11+16+30))in];;
title 'Painting';
title2'Common colours per cohort';
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Using this, I found the table columns were actually too wide, being notably wider than both the values and column titles (link to table here: https://ibb.co/d64nvK). When testing this with other data, the table couldn't fit on a portrait view despite the values and column titles not taking up that much room.

Would there be a way to tailor the table length more specifically to both the table values and column titles?

Comment: Instead of using relative column widths did you try `width=##.# IN` directly ?  If you want auto-fitting columns, consider `ODS EXCEL` instead of `RTF`

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to. I had previously used "width=7" directly

Comment: width=7, without a sizing unit (such as INch). The sample code formula denominator maps the sum of the widths without units to 10 inches, and the numerator is for computing the fractional part of the summed width for the column.  * 10 is for scaling to presumed available real estate in a landscape orientated page.

Comment: Using `width=7in` or `width=7 in` produces an error. Using `style=width=7in` produces columns that are overall more misaligned than before. Sadly I need to produce my graphs in .rtf form, but I do like your Excel suggestion.

Comment: Read up more on the documentation for the `define` column styling specifier, the most specific variant is `/ style=[cellwidth=1.1in]`.  Again, you don't want 7in, you want 10 * 7 / (7+11+16+30), which is 1.1in.  The actual papersize page space is 11" width x 8.5" height (landscape). The 10" presumes, 0.5" left and right margin